# Is it possible to use a JSON property for $.data()?

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to push JSON into a div.

data[i].restaurant.name ideally goes in the div as text.
data[i].restaurant.ambienceRating ideally goes in the div as .data("ambienceRating")

That's what im trying to accomplish anyhow.

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        console.log(data[0].restaurant.ambienceRating);
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            output+="<li id=" + i + ">" + data[i].restaurant.name + "</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("films").innerHTML=output;

});
```

How and where should I push the ambienceRating to be able to retrieve it later?
I tried putting `$( this ).data("ambienceRating", data[i].restaurant.ambienceRating)` into the for-loop but it comes out as a [Object object] string.

EDIT:
Logging ( this ) inside the for-loop returns the data.json object

data[i].restaurant.ambienceRating is "10" (a string, NaN)

http://jsfiddle.net/techii/JtQyr/

Comment: Are you sure it's not an object with properties rather than a string? alerting an object or printing it as a string will give you `"[object Object]"`

Comment: when doing `console.log(data[0].restaurant.ambienceRating);` i get 10. Can the 10 still be an object?

Comment: `TypeError: data[0].restaurant.ambienceRating.type is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

console.log(data[0].restaurant.ambienceRating.type());`

Comment: What does `this` reference in your code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I'm hoping it would reference the <li> tag, but if it's not then I dont know how to target the li and give it a datavalue inside the for loop.

Comment: This references data.json, not the li

Comment: Then what are you logging to test that you are getting `[object Object]`? you should be getting `undefined` if you're testing the li!

Comment: I'm not logging anything to get `[object Object]` it shows up appended to my string! `Name of restaurantobject Object`

Comment: Ok, so `[object Object]` is appearing as the text inside the LI? that isn't at all what you are saying in you question. That means `data[i].restaurant.name` is an object and you need to access the property within it that contains your text. `data[i].restaurant.name.SOMEPROPERTY`

Comment: nono, you misunderstand. If i only have `data[i].restaurant.name` in the for-loop it shows up fine. But i also want to give the li some data values (as explained in the OP). When i attempt to do so, i get the `[object Object]` displayed directly after the `restaurant.name`

Comment: Can you post what you attempted in your question?

Comment: Did an edit to OP, ambienceRating is NaN it's a string = 10. Does that affect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the data to the li by adding a data attribute to the li.

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        console.log(data[0].restaurant.ambienceRating);
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            output+="<li data-ambience-rating='" + data[i].restaurant.ambienceRating + "' id='" + i + "'>" + data[i].restaurant.name + "</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("films").innerHTML=output;

});
```

Now you can access it later with `console.log( $(oneli).data("ambienceRating") )`

Comment: `console.log($('li[id=1]').data("ambienceRating"))` just says undefined atm. I don't get how the data() method works.. I figured maybe you could do `data("data-ambience-rating")` but that doesn't work either.. Thanks for trying to help out!

Comment: If it still says undefined after using the data attribute, you must not be targeting the correct LI. Are you using the HTML5 datatype? (id's can't start with a numeric value in HTML4) Are your ID's unique? (ID's MUST be unique)

Comment: Id's are unique. 1 through 21. I am using `<!doctype html>`. I'll get a JSfiddle together for you. brb

Comment: updated OP with jsfiddle. JSON is in a pastebin, dno how to include it properly, but ill work on parsing it inline with parseJSON